# SwiftUI Firebase data disappearing from view after certain time

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I have a view in my app that fetches vehicle data from a firebase datastore and displays it on the users screen. When the user opens up the screen to view a specific vehicle report the data displays no problem however after 30 seconds of not touching the screen the data completely disappears and the screen turns white. If when you load the data and you scroll up and down on the screen now and again the data stays displayed. It seems like the populated variables are clear after a certain time of inactivity. Any advice?

```
struct ViewSpecificReport: View {

@AppStorage("currentPageSearch") var currentPageSearch = 1
@AppStorage("currentNumberPlate") var currentPlate = "AA00AAA"
@ObservedObject var specificModel = ViewModel()
@State private var isLoading = false

var body: some View {
    ScrollView (showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            
            //Push everything to the left
            HStack {
                Spacer()
            }
            
            //Print report details
            ForEach (specificModel.list) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("General")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("Mileage: " + item.mileage)
                    Text("Date: " + item.date)
                    Text("Email: " + item.email)
                    Text("Phone No: " + item.phoneNo)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Wheels & Tyres")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("N/S Front: " + item.nsFront)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.nsFrontOption))
                    Text("O/S Front: " + item.osFront)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.osFrontOption))
                    Text("N/S Rear: " + item.nsRear)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.nsRearOption))
                    Text("O/S Rear: " + item.osRear)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.osRearOption))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("External & Electrical")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("Glass / Mirror / Bodywork: " + item.glass)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.glassOption))
                    Text("Exterior Lights: " + item.lights)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.lightsOption))
                    Text("Horn / Wipers / Washers: " + item.horn)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.hornOption))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Underbonnet")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("Engine Oil / Coolant Level: " + item.engineOil)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.engineOilOption))
                    Text("Water / Oil / Fluid Leaks: " + item.water)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.waterOption))
                    Text("Auxiliary Belt / Battery: " + item.altBelt)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.altBeltOption))
                    Text("Power Steering / Hydraulic Fluid: " + item.powerSteering)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.powerSteeringOption))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Brakes & Hubs")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("Brake Fluid: " + item.master)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.masterOption))
                    Text("Pads / Discs / Wheel Bearings: " + item.pads)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.padsOption))
                    Text("Hoses / Pipes / Cables: " + item.hoses)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.hosesOption))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Underside")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("Exhaust System / Catalyst: " + item.exhaust)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.exhaustOption))
                    Text("Steering / Suspension: " + item.steering)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.steeringOption))
                    Text("Driveshafts / Oil Leaks: " + item.driveshafts)
                        .foregroundColor(colorChoice(condition: item.driveshaftsOption))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Signatures")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text("Customer Signature: " + item.customerSignature)
                    Text("Technician Signature: " + item.technicianSignature)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                
            }
            
            //Loading animation
            if isLoading {
                ZStack {
                        Color(.white)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                        
                        ProgressView()
                            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .black))
                            .scaleEffect(1.2)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .toolbar {
            Button("Close") {
                currentPageSearch = 1
            }
    }
    //.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Report - \(currentPlate)"))
    .onAppear{
        getDataFromFirebase()
    }
}

func getDataFromFirebase() {
    isLoading = true
    
    specificModel.GetSpecificData(numberplate: currentPlate)
    
    //Slow it down a tiny bit to display
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        isLoading = false
    }
}

func colorChoice(condition: String) -> Color {
    
    if condition == "Green" {
        return Color.green
    }
    
    if condition == "Amber" {
        return Color.yellow
    }
    
    if condition == "Red" {
        return Color.red
    }
    
    return Color.green
}
```

}

Comment: Tough to say without a [mre]. One thing for sure, use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` for observable objects owned by the view. Depending on your setup, this may solve it.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the issue! For my knowledge do you mind explaining why that solved the issue?

Comment: I'd suggest searching for "StateObject vs ObservableObject" -- you'll find a lot of existing writing out there